# Xcode8 + macOS Sierra upload gives Build Error email related to NSCameraUsageDescription

Tags: admob, chartboost

In macOS Sierra, uploaded new build and got below error message email.
    Dear developer,

> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "Real Bike Car Racing - Super Vertigo Run Free Game". To process
>   your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
>
> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the
>   user how the app uses this data.
>
> Though you are not required to fix the following issues, we wanted to make you aware of them:

---

**Updates** : Fixed problem by updating plist entry

---

[image]

```
Privacy - Camera Usage Description : $(PRODUCT_NAME) uses Camera
```

Comment: Are you using AdMob?

Comment: yes, using Admob and Chartboost

Comment: Update to version 7.11.0: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/download

Comment: already used 7.11.0

Comment: I'd suspect its an issue with Chartboost then. Contact them and ask why they need access to `NSCameraUsageDescription`.